# how to save username and password in cache ? react-native

Tags: react-native

*I try to save my Username and Password in cache. I couldnt save two data so I try to save just username below code.*

but when I enter letter to TextInput, data goes to

> savedata()

*but here, this.setState doesnt work I dont know why. Because when render page,*

> console.log("mykey : ", this.state.mykey );

*gives me empty object*

**here is code**

```
<View style={styles.ChildViewStyle}>

    <TextInput
        value = {this.state.mykey}
        placeholder= "Kullanıcı Adı"
        placeholderTextColor="#fff"
        onChangeText={(text) =>  this.savedata(text)}
        keyboardType='email-address'
        onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
        style={styles.input}
    />

</View>
```

**here is my methods**

```
savedata = (value) => {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("myKey", value);
    this.setState({myKey: value});

    console.log("deneme",value);
}

componentDidMount(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey").then((value) => {
        this.setState({myKey: value});
        console.log("didmounth : ", value)
    }).done();
}
```

**Also how can I save two value which are username and password ?**

Answer (score 2):

You could try to store json as string and later parse json during get

```
savedata = (username,password) => {
 let value = {'username' : username, 'password':password}   
 await AsyncStorage.setItem('myKey', JSON.stringify(value));
    this.setState({myKey: value});

    console.log("deneme",value);
} 

constructor(){
    AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey").then((value) => {
         if (value){
         let valueParsed = JSON.parse(value)        
         this.setState({myKey: valueParsed});
         console.log("didmounth : ", valueParsed)
         }    
})
}
```

Comment: [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#setitem) only saves strings so trying to save an object will cause an error.

Comment: @Andrew well you can using "JSON.stringfy(objName)" to save objects without error

Comment: can you have look at this example to store json https://medium.com/@luisbajana/saving-objects-using-asyncstorage-2d8696275667

Comment: @Nino9612 Yeah I know :) But the original answer didn't use `JSON.parse` or `JSON.stringify` so it wouldn't work and would cause an error :(

Comment: @Andrew thanks for reminding me to use parse. now it works :)

Comment: @AbdullaThanseeh  in componentdidmount, this.state is not work . because component is not render

Comment: @hakan yeah setstate is not possible in componentDidMount instead use it in con structor

Comment: @AbdullaThanseeh I used like  this;   constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        AsyncStorage.getItem("myKey").then((values) => {
         
                let valuePrsed = JSON.parse(values);
                this.setState({myKey: valuePrsed});
                console.log("didmounth : ", valuePrsed)
            
        }).done();
      }              but still it  is not render component

Comment: I want to use recorded datas but I cant set them to state object

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncStorage.setItem` and `this.setState` are [async funtion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), so your console.log() will not be work as you wish. To console you can try

```
savedata = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("myKey", value);
    this.setState({myKey: value}, () => {
      console.log("deneme",value);
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Store error');
  }
}
```

Comment: console.log("deneme",value);   this code is work in my code too. but as I said in render,     when I use console.log("mykey : ", this.state.mykey ) it gives me empty object

Comment: add the line of code: `console.log('render')` on your render() method to recognize if your component render

Comment: yeah it renders

Comment: It means that `this.setState()` method worked. Let try return on saveData() method 
`savedata = async (value) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem("myKey", value);
    return this.setState({myKey: value}, () => {
      console.log("deneme",value);
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Store error');
  }
}`

Comment: It helped me @vuluu thx bro. but I want to ask that what 
asyc and await do  here  savedata = asyc (value) =>  await