# How to setState from local storage in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, web-deployment

I have SiteData stored in another file and I want to setState to this data when user visit website for the first time than as he/she does changes in the website I want to store it in localstorage and when user visits website again I want them to show them previous changes. So I don't want to fetch data from SiteData file. I am doing this in componentWillMount lifecycle.

```js
componentWillMount() {
  localStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SiteData'));
  if (ls === null) {
    this.setState({
      MyData: SiteData
    });
    localStorage.setItem('SiteData',JSON.stringify( this.state.MyData));
  }
  else {
    console.log("ls");
    this.setState({
      MyData: ls
    });
  }
}
```

I am getting this error :

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

P.S. : I have properly Exported SiteData(export default SiteData)

Comment: post your entire component

Comment: you can follow this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920809/how-to-save-username-and-password-in-cache-react-native/54920910?noredirect=1#comment96607580_54920910

Comment: Probably there is some error in your render function

Comment: Please post your `render`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! The code you have shown is not a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and so readers can't run it to try reproducing what you see. Please edit the description to make the code a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that I had a Completly different problem as I was trying to save data in local storage which had dependencies on other components. So local storage was ignoring these dependencies and due to that when I use local storage data in the state I got this error. Solved this by making few changes in SiteData. Thanks, everyone for the help.

Answer (score -1):

At a guess, you are binding one name (‘localStorage’) but then referring to a completely different name (‘ls’). In the snippet you presented, ‘ls’ is never bound and so will always be `undefined`.

Does this work better for you?

```js
componentWillMount() {
  localStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SiteData'));
  if (localStorage === null) {
    this.setState({
      MyData: SiteData
    });
    localStorage.setItem('SiteData',JSON.stringify( this.state.MyData));
  }
  else {
    console.log("localStorage");
    this.setState({
      MyData: localStorage
    });
  }
}
```